# Delete/Change tag

Tags: discussion

I tried to create a tag "RaspberryPiOS" which got converted into the less than memorable "raspberrypios". I prefer CamelCase to hyphens or underscores, but this is apparently not permitted.

I am unable to create "raspberry-pi-os", which makes more sense.

How can I delete the tag "raspberrypios"?

I think the tag "Raspbian" should become an alias for a tag representing the new OS, although  others may have different ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[raspberrypios](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberrypios) has no questions so the system will [automatically clean it up within 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40724/295232) (unless somebody else uses the tag in the meantime). I think that after that happens, you'll be able to create [raspberry-pi-os](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-os); tag names on Stack Exchange are usually in [kebab case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kebab_case).

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with making the new tag an alias for Raspbian. The new Pi OS will likely diverge and answers would not apply to Raspbian. But aliasing the tag would imply that all future changes were backward compatible.

It would also be a moving target as it is safe to assume that the new Pi OS will have multiple versions (even beyond the 32/64 bit variations). So would the alias point to Pi OS version one or two etc.